# How to export dataframe to Excel and print only new rows of dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a python program which prints discrepancies in odds which have been scraped from various bookmakers. This is achieved by appending the odds to a pandas dataframe. I want to export the dataframe to Excel, everytime I run the python file so that the program does not print duplicate discrepancies in odds. This could be achieved by referring to the Excel sheet to see if the horse's name is already there, when printing the dataframe. I don't want the Excel sheet to completely wipe itself everytime the program runs though.

Here is an example of the output of the dataframe:

```
            Race             Horse      Bookmaker   Odds  AvgOdds
13     Mackay R1        Which Lily  SportsBetting   2.45     2.04
15     Mackay R1        Which Lily         Bet365   2.40     2.04
17     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Ubet   9.00     7.26
18     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter        BetEasy   8.50     7.26
19     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Neds   8.50     7.26
...          ...               ...            ...    ...      ...
1545  Mackay R10        Cold Power  SportsBetting   8.10     6.39
1547  Mackay R10        Cold Power         Bet365   8.00     6.39
1548  Mackay R10   All Star Rocket           Ubet   7.20     2.98
1560  Mackay R10           Dawlish      Sportsbet  14.00    11.65
1561  Mackay R10           Dawlish  SportsBetting  15.20    11.65
```

Here is the part of my code relating to dataframes:

```
cols1 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Bookmaker', 'Odds']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
cols2 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Bookmaker', 'AvgOdds']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols2)
df3 = df2.groupby(by='Horse', sort=False).mean()
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df4 = round(df3,2)
dfmerge = pd.merge(df1,df4,on='Horse',how='inner')
dfmerge2 = dfmerge[dfmerge['Odds']>dfmerge['AvgOdds']*1.15]
print(dfmerge2)
```

Comment: what would be better if you add a timestamp to your program and add it as a column in your file, you can then see what's new(er) and what's not based on your keys and take the newer of the keys which will be based on your timestamp - this is a pretty simple data concept see [data delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding#:~:text=The%20differences%20are%20recorded%20in,encoding%20greatly%20reduces%20data%20redundancy.)

Comment: Whether or not the rows are new or old is not a problem for me. I want to refine the dataframe as much as possible everytime it runs so it is easier to read when I place bets.